# CSS float function for multiple image does not work. (vertical line of image and test is inconsistent)

Tags: css, image

I tried to make several lines of containers, each container has image and text.
to do this, I used {float:left} function , but the left side of the images is not vertically consistent to each other like below.

[image link:the used codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdDei.png)

[image link:the result of the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjKmz.png)

I want to make this like :

(red box) Hello

(blue box) My name is

(green box) Story

(purple box) Song

Please give some advices.

Answer (score 0):

put your all elements in a div and add display:flex to your new-div item:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
   <div>Hello1</div>
   <div>my Name is</div> 
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>Hello2</div>
   <div>my Name is</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

style:

```
.parent{display:flex;}
```

Comment: I added {display:flex;} in class ".center_item" , but the problem of showing like step-down shaped image group is still existing.  
(red box) Hello
        (blue box) My name is
                (green box) Story
                        (purple box) Song

Comment: you need to put the text with its box in one div like: (updated my code)

Comment: it means you should have four divs in the parent div now.

Comment: thank you, also I used " clearfix " to solve the problem. It works well.

Comment: welcom, anytime :)